# Stop windows-7 explorer taskbar icon changing for different locations

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, taskbar

If I open an instance of Windows Explorer, a button appears on the taskbar; its icon matches the icon of current location in Explorer. E.g. If I've clicked on a drive (e.g. C:) then the taskbar icon changes to the drive icon. If I select the Pictures Library location, the taskbar icon changes to a little picture symbol.

How can I stop this behaviour, so that the taskbar icon always shows the same icon, regardless of where I've clicked in Explorer?

Comment: It would be interesting to know the possible reason for such behaviour.

Comment: I guess if you have several Explorer windows open, it helps you distinguish the different task bar buttons. But I find it more helpful to always have the same icon for a particular application.

Comment: I often do not realize i have explorer open to a particular folder because the icon shows something other than a folder. My mind just skips it when alt-tabing for it. Eventually, there are multiple copies of explorer open to the same folder.

Comment: This "feature" drives me nuts. It is a serious disruption to work flow. I go to move or copy of file and my thoughts come to a crashing halt cause windows has switched the explorers icon from the friendly yellow folder to something less obvious. Documents? Nope, not a folder any more. Now its a page of text. One drive?  Nope, now it is the cloud icon. I;m sure there are those who love this, but for me it just wastes time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible (if you don't want to edit shell32.dll resources).

Some folder use a desktop.ini file to specify the icon; you can change the icon removing the row in that file

Go to My Pictures folder, click on the address bar and add (at the end of the address) " \desktop.ini "

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21779
InfoTip=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-12688
IconResource=%SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll,-113
IconFile=%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll
IconIndex=-236
[LocalizedFileNames]
Sample Pictures.lnk=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21805
```

Just remove all "Icon" parameters.

However I don't think it's possible to do it for any folder on your drive